# Inconsistent online radius value for Proxima Centauri

Tags: size

I was looking up the radius of Proxima Centauri and got a funny result.

Google says it's about 100,000 km, while WolframAlpha says its about 200,000 km.  Are the error bars that big, or does someone have some bad numbers?

Comment: I had not realised either were in the business of measuring stellar radii. Were no original sources quoted?

Comment: One answer is half of the other; you're certain no-one has confused radius and diameter?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wikipedia quotes $0.1542\pm 0.0045$ solar radii which is $107276\,km$ with an error of about $3130\, km$.

They also give a reference to a 2017 paper available on Arxiv [*Proxima's orbit around Alpha Centauri*, P. Kervella, F. Thévenin, C. Lovis](https://arxiv.org/abs/1611.03495) that gives this value.

Wolfram's estimate is too far off to be an experimental error, IMO, and I think someone has just inadvertently used the diameter (twice the radius) rather than the radius.